# To sum up values of same items in a list of tuples while they are string

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

If I have list of tuples like this:

```
my_list = [('books', '$5'), ('books', '$10'), ('ink', '$20'), ('paper', '$15'), ('paper', '$20'), ('paper', '$15')]
```

how can I turn the list to this:

```
[('books', '$15'), ('ink', '$20'), ('paper', '$50')]
```

i.e. to add the expense of same item while both the items are string in the tuples. I have problem with the price items being string. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

I am getting the first list in this way:

```
my_list=[]
for line in data:
        item, price  = line.strip('\n').split(',') 
        cost = ["{:s}".format(item.strip()), "${:.2f}".format(float(price))]
        my_list.append(tuple(cost))
```

Now `my_list` should look like given above.

Comment: Please check out the formatting options in the editor. Highlight code section, then press `Ctrl-K`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you store the cost as a string prefixed by a `$` instead of simply a `float`?

Comment: @Holt: You wouldn't want `float` for monetary values; imprecision can kill you. `decimal.Decimal` for all financial calculations.

Comment: @ShadowRanger true, but the question stay the same with `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: The requirement of the problem is that the output would be displayed like: [('books', '$15'), ('ink', '$20'), ('paper', '$50')]

Comment: @Korchagin You should make a difference between what  you really store and what  you print, there is no need to store cost as string and it complicates your code, you should store the value as `int` or `decimal.Decimal` as pointed out by @ShadowRanger and only add the `$` when printing the values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to do this:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> my_list = [('books', '$5'), ('books', '$10'), ('ink', '$20'), ('paper', '$15'), ('paper', '$20'), ('paper', '$15')] 
>>> res = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item, price in my_list:
...     res[item].append(int(price.strip('$')))
... 
>>> total = [(k, "${}".format(sum(v))) for k, v in res.items()]
>>> total
[('ink', '$20'), ('books', '$15'), ('paper', '$50')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy using a dictionary:

```
result={} #initialize an empty dictionary
for (type,cost) in my_list:
    if type not in result.keys():
        result[type]=int(cost[1:]) #add entry
    else:
        result[type]=result[type]+int(cost[1:]) #increment cost

#make dictionary a list again
dictlist=[]
for key, value in result.iteritems():
    temp = [key,"$"+str(value)] #add dollar sign
    dictlist.append(temp)

print dictlist
```

Edit: forgot two lines

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a dictionary to solve this problem.

```
my_list = [('books', '$5'), ('books', '$10'), ('ink', '$20'),
       ('paper', '$15'), ('paper', '$20'), ('paper', '$15')]

sums = {}
for item, price in my_list:
    sums[item] = sums.get(item, 0) + int(price[1:])

print sums
```

And if you need list of tuples, just do

```
print sums.items()
```

And to get your the output you expect,

```
print [(item, '$' + str(price)) for item, price in sums.items()]
```

**Update**

If you have costs with floating point value, you can simply change `int` to `float` like this and rest of the code remains the same,

```
sums[item] = sums.get(item, 0) + float(price[1:])
```

Comment: will you delete this one also and write another answer if you get another downvote?

Comment: It was my fault not reading the question at first. Then I got it and answered properly. I thought posting a new answer world be helpful and if that is a bad thing why is there an option to post multiple answers. Btw, if you downvoted just because of that, I would question your obedience to this sites guidelines. and no i will not delete this answer.

Comment: How would it be if I have: my_list = [('milk', '$2.35'), ('bread', '$1.95'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$2.38'), ('milk', '$2.31'), ('bread', '$1.90')]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is already grouped like you sample input, you can use [*itertools.groupby*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), grouping by each first element of the tuples and summing the prices in each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

my_list = [('books', '$5'), ('books', '$10'), ('ink', '$20'), ('paper', '$15'), ('paper', '$20'), ('paper', '$15')]

grouped = [(k, "${}".format(sum(int(s[1][1:]) for s in v)))    
               for k ,v in groupby(my_list, itemgetter(0))]
```

Output:

```
[('books', '$15'), ('ink', '$20'), ('paper', '$50')]
```

If it were not ordered you could call sorted  `groupby(sorted(my_list), itemgetter(0))` but changes the complexity to `n log n` so a dict option may be better in that case.

You can also do the groupby on `data` and forget building an intermediary list, `csv.reader` will also split the data for you:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

from csv import reader
grouped = [(k, "${}".format(sum(int(s[1]) for s in v))) 
              for k, v in groupby(reader(data), itemgetter(0))]
```

You might be better also leaving the values as ints and formatting when you want to output. Also to handle floats cast to float not int:

```
from csv import reader
grouped = [(k, sum(float(s[1]) for s in v))
              for k, v in groupby(reader(data), itemgetter(0))]
```

When you want to output you can add the dollar sign and also pad so you get nicely formatted output:

```
In [10]: "${:.2f}".format(1.0)
Out[10]: '$1.00'
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how would it be in case, my_list = [('milk', '$2.35'), ('bread', '$1.95'), ('chips', '$2.54'), ('milk', '$2.38'), ('milk', '$2.31'), ('bread', '$1.90')]

Comment: Just use float instad of int

Comment: I could fix it. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score -1):

Just for fun, a one-liner:

```
[(k,'$'+str(sum(int(e[1][1:]) for e in my_list if e[0]==k))) for k in set(map(lambda x:x[0], my_list))]
```

Don't actually do this.